# Error installing Ruby with RVM: make "-j" argument

Tags: ruby, makefile, rvm

I have followed the instructions on [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) website to install it on my Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. Now when I try to install Ruby I get a building error:

```
$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3
(...)
ruby-1.9.3-p429 - #compiling...........................................
Error running 'make -j 4'
```

Reading the make log I found:

```
make: the `-j' option requires a positive integral argument
```

If I pass it the number of processes, I get the following:

```
$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3 -j 2
(...)
Error running 'make -j 4 -j2'
```

I have tried other versions and get the same error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that somehow make is being invoked with `'-j 4'`, that is, the space is being included in the argument, which means `make` is trying to parse the string `" 4"` (space + 4) as a number and space is not an integer so it fails.

Have you done something like add a line like this to your rvmrc file:

```
export rvm_make_flags="-j 4"
```

?  You should remove the whitespace here, it should just be `"-j4"`.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem, but I don't really remember of modifying  that file. Thanks.